# Get the last day of a month BUT just the number with Vuejs or JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the last day of a month, it worked but it displays a very long description and I just need the day.

My code is this one:

```
var today = new Date();
var data = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);
```

and it returns

```
Sat Apr 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0400
```

But I just want to get the 30... only that

how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Stack Overflow encourage developer laziness?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/does-stack-overflow-encourage-developer-laziness)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getDate()` to get the day of the month.

```js
var today = new Date();
var data = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate(); // 30
```

Answer (score 0):

getDate() returns the day of the month

```
var today = new Date();
var data = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);
var date = data.getDate();
```